# Flex play a series of sound files

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, timer, audio

So I am making an app that plays a series sound files based on the input. For example the inout can be "Smile Cry Scream" then the three corresponding sounds will be play in sequence. For now I play a sound then start a timer, which upon completion trigger the next sound and so on. I don't use the delay parameter of the Timer because it is a little buggy.Is there a better way of.doing this, especially when the interval between sounds gets smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `Event.SOUND_COMPLETE` event on the `SoundChannel` object to launch a new sound from your sounds array, if there are more to launch. Like this:

```
var _sounds:Vector.<Sound>=new Vector.<Sound>();
var _sc:SoundChannel;
var _isPlaying:Boolean=false;
function channelASound(sound:Sound):void {
    _sounds.push(sound);
    checkPlay();
}
function checkPlay(e:Event=null):void {
    if ((_isPlaying)&&(e==null)) return; // we've been called from channelASound
    // with playback still going
    if (_sc) _sc.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,checkPlay);
    // otherwise we need to start another playback. Cleaning up first
    if (_sounds.length==0) {
        // nothing more to play. Not the case if called from channelASound
        _sc=null;
        _isPlaying=false;
        return;
    }
    _sc=_sounds.shift().play();
    _sc.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,checkPlay);
    _isPlaying=true;
}
```

How does this work: You call `channelASound` for each of the "Smile Cry Scream" or other sequence of sounds, one per call, in the desired order for them to play. Then `checkPlay()` is called, to check if there's a playback and if there's something more to play. There will be more playback if we have just channeled a something, but if there's currently playback goung on, the `isPlaying` will be true and we'll return right there. Otherwise, we start a new playback using `_sounds.pop()` as the next sound to be played, assign the channel to `_sc`, add a listener and set `_isPlaying` to true. If the function is triggered by a listener, the event parameter is not null, so we're not returning ASAP but instead clean the old data and the listener from `_sc` and check for more playback. If no playback, we set flag to false and clear the `_sc` variable, if there's more playback, we start next sound.

Comment: thanks for the help I'll test it out. Just one question though, how do you include a variable for the delay between two sounds into this implementation?

Comment: You can as well use a silence sound for delay. In case you need a variable delay, create a long enough sound of silence, create a corresponding array of starting positions alongside `_sounds`, say `_positions`, provide a position parameter into `channelASound` with default value of 0 and store that value into positions array, and use `_positions.shift()` as the starting position for the current sound. Everything else should remain intact.

Comment: You can also use a sample data approach to make a long silence instead of embedding it, because silence consists of only zeroes. You listen on `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA` ona certain `Sound` object of your creation, and make the listener fill the sound data with at least 8192 pairs of zeroes per call (one zero per channel) until a certain amount has been stuffed (44100*length in seconds), then you return, this makes Flash not request more data sampling, and your sound is ready.